# Xib fatal error

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a .xib called `ContentView.xib` and set it custom class to a subview of UIView. I get this error when I try and run the app:

```
fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented:
```

Here is my code:

```
class ContentView: UIView {


    override init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: Screen.width,
            height: Screen.height))


        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ContentView", owner: self, options: nil)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented:")
    }
```

I have looked up about NSCoder and couldn't find anything to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this code:

```
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented:")
```

You are raising an assertion and crashing the app by yourself, remove that code, everything work well.

Comment: Thank you for that, it has stopped crashing. But the view from the .xib still won't appear?

Comment: @StephenFox Because you should put your setup in the `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method for views from XIBs.

Comment: @StephenFox: Did you set the class for that xib ? And also load the setup code in initwithcoder not in init for xib's

Comment: Yes, I have `ContentView.xib` 's custom class set to `ContentView` in Xcode. Do I need to set anything with Files Owner?

Comment: Write `NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ContentView", owner: self, options: nil)` this inside initwithcoder